# If something moves at an infinite speed how long does it take to traverse infinity?

Tags: kinematics, mathematics, singularities

If something moves at an infinite speed how long does it take to traverse infinity?

If the answer is infinite time, then is there something greater than infinity such that something can traverse infinity in 0 seconds or less than 1 second?

Comment: Luckily for physicists nothing moves at infinite speed, and therefore there is no need to answer this question in the context of physics.

Comment: @ThePhoton while yes such things don't (possibly) occur, it doesn't mean models won't spit things out involving infinite distances in finite time, and when they do they need careful unwrapping and interpretation.  for example, diffusion processes can yield solutions on the semi-infinite line moving mass in finite time.  'Simple' Newtonian mechanics can do the same thing when considering collisions of four bodies.  It's a shame this question was shot down so quickly as it holds within it a lot of interesting discussion stemming from genuine curiosity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\Delta t=\Delta x/v$.  So in your question $\Delta t =\infty/\infty$ which is a standard indeterminate form. It could be 0, it could be infinite, or it could be any finite value. You have to use some other information to find it, usually by taking a limit.

Answer (score 1):

IF something could travel with infinite speed, then instead of travelling between A and B, it would be at every point in between. In fact, it would be at every possible location simultaneously.

But whether or not it could "traverse infinity" is a malformed question. There is no infinite distance.